Salesforce Maps: How to pass boundaries to a custom Lightning Web Component
I've created a custom action "Test" into Salesforce Maps

It opens a new LWC component, which calls an API that gets property records located within the boundaries.

My question is : how can I get the boundaries (2 in this sample) from the SF Map to send to the LWC component? I have it hardcoded for now.
Thanks in advance for the help!
